# How do I get referrer value in NextJS in Client Component

Tags: next.js

I am using App Router for NextJS and [`next/headers`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/headers) are available if you are using Server Component.

However this does not work in Client Component and I can't find a way to get referrer value.

Does anybody know how to get values?

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple ways to get the `referrer`.

You can either use the referrer from the DOM. Which would look like this in React.

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const ClientComponent = () => {
  const [referrer, setReferrer] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    const referrer = document.referrer;
    setReferrer(referrer);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      Referrer: {referrer}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ClientComponent;
```

Or you can use the `headers()` function from NextJS. An example for this approach would look like this:

```js
import { headers } from 'next/headers';
    
export default function ClientPage() {
    const requestHeaders = headers();
    const referrer = requestHeaders.get('referrer');
    
    return (
        <div>
            Referrer: {referrer}
        </div>
    );
}
```